# Availability of location-based sleep datasets?

Tags: geospatial, medical

I am interested in spatial patterns of sleep quality (e.g. differences between neighborhoods in the same city, or even streets).

Is there any interesting sleep dataset that contains the location?
I am aware of the datasets listed at the [National Sleep Research Resource](https://sleepdata.org), but they don't include any geographic data.

Did anyone have luck getting data obtained with apps like [Sleep Cycle](https://www.sleepcycle.com) for research? They publish aggregated statistics, but it seems that getting the data is not possible (which is understandable given the sensitivity, but I am still hoping for any related dataset).

Comment: Some researchers have used cell phone location data to assess spatiotemporal patterns in sleep: https://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty_pages/keith.chen/.  However, access to this data is likely to be restricted.